# How do I run a class in a WAR from the command line?

Tags: java, jar, war

I have a Java class which has a main and I used to run as a standalone app from the command line e.g.

```
java -jar myjar.jar params
```

I needed to repackage the code to run under apache and all my code, including the entry point class from the old jar, has ended up in a WAR file for easy deplyment into the web server.

However, I still want to be able to run it from the command line and the code has not changed and is all in there, I just can't figure out how to get it to run.

Here's what I tried...

I presumed the WAR was just like a jar, so

```
java -jar mywar.war params
```

That failed saying there was no main class defined in the manifest.

I manually added a manifest to the war and tried again, with the same effect.

I noticed that in my war I had a folder called META-INF containing a manifest.mf, so I added a line to that declaring my main class as I would to a normal manifest...

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: mypackage.MyEntryPointClass
```

This gave a `noClassDefFoundError mypackage.MyEntryPointClass`, which is progress of a sort.  That led me to believe that it was just a path issue, so I tried

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: WEB-INF.classes.mypackage.MyEntryPointClass
```

I now get the same error, but with a stack trace...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WEB-INF/classes/mypackage/MyEntryPointClass (wrong name: mypackage/MyEntryPointClass)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

I've googled for a bit but can't find anything which answers my question, and I read a couple of other questions here which are slightly different, so I thought I would post.

Java 1.5, not that I think that should make any difference.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but what about adding a 'Class-Path' entry to the manifest?

Comment: Have you any reasons for this? Why won't you try to keep two different assemblies - one for web and one as a standalone application?

Comment: Did you try putting a classpath in the manifest.mf which had WEB-INF/classes and leave the Main-Class as mypackage.MyEntryPointClass
?

Comment: tried the classpath idea, didn't work

Comment: @Andrew, I could have two different packages, it just seems wasteful when the content of one is a superset of the content of the other

Answer (score 70):

Similar to what Richard Detsch but with a bit easier to follow (works with packages as well)

Step 1: Unwrap the War file.

```
jar -xvf MyWar.war
```

Step 2: move into the directory

```
cd WEB-INF
```

Step 3: Run your main with all dependendecies

```
java -classpath "lib/*:classes/." my.packages.destination.FileToRun
```

Comment: the answer I was looking for

Comment: Can this be done without unzipping? The environment I run my stuff on is more tightly constrained than this.

Comment: For windows change the `: -> ;` so the above command becomes `java -classpath "lib/*;classes/." my.packages.destination.FileToRun` specifically change

Answer (score 56):

You can do what [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (continuous integration project) does.
you download a war which can be deployed in tomcat or to execute using

```
java -jar hudson.war
```

(Because it has an embedded Jetty engine, running it from command line cause a server to be launched.) Anyway  by looking at  hudson's manifest I understand that they put a Main class in the root for the archive. In your case your war layout should be look like:

under root:

- mypackage/MyEntryPointClass.class
- WEB-INF/lib
- WEB-INF/classes
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

while the manifest should include the following line:

```
Main-Class: mypackage.MyEntryPointClass
```

please notice that the  mypackage/MyEntryPointClass.class  is accessable from the command line only, and the classes under WEB-INF/classes are accessable from the application server only.

HTH

Comment: Not gonna downvote because the answer contains some good info.  However, it does not answer the original question "...run as a standalone app from the command line..."

Answer (score 10):

A war is a webapp. If you want to have a console/standalone application reusing the same classes as you webapp, consider packaging your shared classes in a jar, which you can put in `WEB-INF/lib`. Then use that jar from the command line.
Thus you get both your console application, and you can use the same classes in your servlets, without making two different packages.
This, of course, is true when the war is exploded.

Comment: Sure but thats not always possible. Sometimes you only have a war and would like to run the main class quickly.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Maven, just follow the `maven-war-plugin` documentation about "[How do I create a JAR containing the classes in my webapp?](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#attached)": add **`<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>`** to the `<configuration>` of the plugin:

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
      <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
    </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The you will have 2 products in the `target/` folder:

- The `project.war` itself
- The `project-classes.jar` which contains all the compiled classes in a jar

Then you will be able to execute a main class using classic method: `java -cp target/project-classes.jar 'com.mycompany.MainClass' param1 param2`

Answer (score 8):

To execute `SomeClass.main(String [] args)` from a deployed war file do:

1. Write class `SomeClass.java` that has a main method method i.e. (*public static void main(String[] args) {...}*)
2. Deploy your WAR
3. `cd /usr/local/<yourprojectsname>/tomcat/webapps/projectName/WEB-INF`
4. `java -cp "lib/jar1.jar:lib/jar2.jar: ... :lib/jarn.jar" com.mypackage.SomeClass arg1 arg2 ... arg3`

Note1: to see if the class `SomeOtherClass.class` is in `/usr/tomcat/webapps/<projectName>/WEB-INF/lib` run:

```
cd /usr/tomcat/webapps/projectName/WEB-INF/lib && 
find . -name '*.jar' | while read jarfile; do if jar tf "$jarfile" | grep SomeOtherClass.class; then echo "$jarfile"; fi; done
```

Note2: Write to standard out so you can see if your main actually works via print statements to the console.  This is called a back door.

Note3: The comment above by Bozhidar Bozhanov seems correct

Comment: this is technically correct, so I gave it a +1, but I don't think this solution is a good idea. It requires building a classpath manually, and is very error prone.

Comment: Agreeing with JBCP above. 
But I'm using Netbeans and in there you can ask for the properties of your Java class, and it has a Runtime Classpath entry that gathers the full absolute classpath (mine is 4000 chars :)  )
Quite a nice way to turn some internals of your webapp into scriptable classes.

Answer (score 7):

The rules of locating classes in an archive file is that the location of the file's package declaration and the location of the file within the archive have to match.  Since your class is located in WEB-INF/classes, it thinks the class is not valid to run in the current context.

The only way you can do what you're asking is to repackage the war so the `.class` file resides in the `mypackage` directory in the root of the archive rather than the WEB-INF/classes directory.  However, if you do that you won't be able to access the file from any of your web classes anymore.

If you want to reuse this class in both the war and outside from the java command line, consider building an executable jar you can run from the command line, then putting that jar in the `war` file's WEB-INF/lib directory.

Answer (score 6):

In [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) project, You can build jar automatically using [Maven War plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) by setting `archiveClasses` to `true`. Example below.

```
<plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
       </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: run maven clean install

Answer (score 2):

the best way if you use Spring Boot is :

1/ Create a ServletInitializer extends **SpringBootServletInitializer** Class
   . With method **configure** which run your Application Class

2/ Generate **always** a maven install **WAR** file

3/ With this artefact you can even :

```
    . start application from war file with java -jar file.war

    . put your war file in your favorite Web App server (like tomcat, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with docker:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps -p 8080:8080 tomcat
```

This is the Windows syntax - for Linux/Mac replace ${PWD} with $(pwd).

A .war file is a Java Servlet web-application archive that is supposed to be ran within so called servlet container, which in practice means Apache Tomcat. The easiest way to do this is to simply run Tomcat which we can do using docker with the above command. Unfortunately, I had no luck running the (legacy) applications I was trying to run - I assume it's a mismatch of the Servlet-API versions.

Comment: This is fantastic - thank you!!!!  Note that I was able to do this by specifying a specific version.  I used `tomcat:9-jdk8` for mine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file), with a WAR file, the classes that get loaded into the classpath are in the "/WEB-INF/classes" and "/WEB-INF/lib" directory.

You could try simply putting a copy of the classes on the root file system of the zip file (which is what a war/jar is).  I'm not sure if that would work though.

You can always just create two separate files.

Comment: putting copies in a public location would deffinitely be ugly

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option, include into the `war` file, the rest service to trigger the application logic via url. Deploy the `war` file onto any web/application server you want.

Then you can start your application via any command-line based HTTP client like `curl` on Linux.

The disadvantage: usually these HTTP clients are different on different OSs. Which is not critical for a lot of cases. Also you can install `curl` on Windows.

Answer (score -3):

It's not possible to run a java class from a WAR file. WAR files have a different structure to Jar files.

To find the related java classes, export (preferred way to use ant) them as Jar put it in your web app lib.

Then you can use the jar file as normal to run java program. The same jar was also referred in web app (if you put this jar in web app lib)