# How to run java class file inside the war file

Tags: java, war

i am having war file called Sample.war. in this war file i have the main class called "Maintest" .i want to run or execute the Maintest class from out side the war .how to do this

Comment: why do you have Main class in war?.. you really need war or jar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021303/566092

Answer (score 4):

War files are just Jar files with extra metadata. So, you should be fine to do:

```
java -classpath application.war Maintest
```

That will load the class *Maintest* from the war file *application.war* and run it

Comment: Classes in wars are placed under WEB-INF/classes.  Your suggestion will not work for these.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10021303/566092 - this should work fine, looks so, haven't tested though.

Answer (score 4):

same answer as I posted here: [How do I run a class in a WAR from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842972/how-do-i-run-a-class-in-a-war-from-the-command-line/33266505#33266505)

Step 1: Unwrap the War file.

```
jar -xvf MyWar.war
```

Step 2: move into the directory

```
cd WEB-INF
```

Step 3: Run your main with all dependendecies

```
java -classpath "lib/*:classes/." my.packages.destination.FileToRun
```

Answer (score 1):

WAR files are intended for servlet container deployment and not for stand-alone execution.

Hence, there is no easy way to do what you want.  Use executable jars for main-method application.

Answer (score 0):

The entry point of a war is not a main method like it is for an application. The entry point of a war would be the web.xml, which is read by the application server and used to map urls to servlets.

If you really need to test a war, you could use an embedded application server like Jetty.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike executable jar there won't be executable war file and why to run class inside war file. Classes inside war files are directly/indirectly loaded by web container/server. if really want to run a class inside a jar which is inside war file, then putting the jar in classpath it can be run as usual.