# MySQL script with event scheduler before spring boot app starts

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, mysql-event

In my app I creating tables with Hibernate annotations, but after this I want to create mysql script to generate raports:

In my resources folder I created `data.sql` :

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS daily_report;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT daily_report
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-01-01'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    DO BEGIN
INSERT INTO daily_report(day_of_report,http_errors,other_errors) VALUES(
    current_date(),
    (select count(*) from error where date(save_date)=current_date() and name="HttpError"),
    (select count(*) from error where date(save_date)=current_date() and name not in("unknown","HttpError")
));
END $$
DELIMITER ;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

All looks good, because when I run:

```
SELECT @@global.event_scheduler;
```

It shows that is ON, but after running:

```
show events
```

It shows no events :( 
`data.sql` script is working because when I run him directly in mysql it works - command `show events` showing that this daily_report scheduled event is working.

Comment: according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581175/running-scripts-in-a-sprint-boot-web-application I changed file to import.sql and it still doesnt work :(

Comment: You may find it helpful for troubleshooting to get your event to run every five minutes; then when it works switch to once day.

Comment: Have you confirmed that account you use for Hibernate db session has EVENT privilege?