# Running many Main classes in a war file

Tags: java, jar, war

I want to run many main classes in a War file. Since I have a lot of classes to run, I cannot make a runnable jar. How can I run the classes?

Comment: Generally a war file implies it's for Servlet(s) and JSP(s). [Answer Unclear Ask Later](http://www.ginifab.com/gift/magic_8_ball_sayings.html).

Comment: WAR and Main class???

Comment: It has some controllers which call Java classes. The Java classes need some background services.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842972/how-do-i-run-a-class-in-a-war-from-the-command-line).  Also, you can have as many main classes in a jar as you like, now if you are specifically asking about an executable jar, different story.