# How to run specific class from war file?

Tags: java, class, maven, jar, war

I have a Maven Web Application that contains only a single class in the Source Packages folder. I have obtained the war file from this project which I would like to copy and run on another machine. I would like to be able to run only that specific class using the commandline.

The reason why I still want to use the war file is because that class implements a RESTful service so I don't know if there is another way to go (like making it a jar and end right there). My war file also contains several dependencies and one of them has the provided scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This is an extract from the pom.xml file and is the only dependency that does not appear in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. However, I don't know if this is the problem.

My class is named `ClientSide` and is under the `client` package. Running the command:

```
    java -cp warFileName.war client.ClientSide
```

resulted in this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class client.ClientSide
```

Adding `Main-Class: client.ClientSide` to the manifest file did not change anything. I have tried the solutions proposed here: [How do I run a class in a WAR from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842972/how-do-i-run-a-class-in-a-war-from-the-command-line/10021303#10021303) but with no luck. This error would keep repeating.

The only way I can run that class is by right-clicking on the class inside the Web Application and select `Run File` from netbeans, which is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>client.ClientSide.YourMain</mainClass>
                    <classpathPrefix>./lib/</classpathPrefix>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

You can put this in your main `pom.xml`, Here you are telling where is your main class

Comment: After adding that plugin I got the following error: `no main manifest attribute, in ClientSideCommunication-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` when I ran the `java -jar ClientSideCommunication-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` command.