# How to run a vaadin8 war from command line?

Tags: java, vaadin, war, vaadin8

I am web-development noob and use vaadin 8 for an application and gradle to build the war-file. How can I run the apllication file from command line?

I tried this without success:

```
java -cp root.war my.namespace.RootServlet
```

The class is not found.

Answer (score 0):

That will only work if you have an embedded servlet container inside the WAR, that is defined as main class in your manifest file. See the following answer to a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804844/8819761