# Running Main Class from War file

Tags: java, war

I need to run class with main method from a war file. I tried java -jar test.war. It dint work. I tried by putting Main-Class entry in MANIFEST.MF file but giving error as NoClassDefFound error.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you need a main method in war file ? Are you running any configuration at server startup ?

Comment: war or jar?....

Comment: I need to update cache in running web application. I don't want to have listener for this as it will effect performance.

Comment: In my case the reason I need it is because I have a special seed data creator to help test my web applicaiton. And yes I know I could create a separate project but in theory I don't see why this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The classes that get loaded into the classpath diffirent with war and jar. Try to change file and you can run with command line.
Suggest this link to help you:
[How do I run a class in a WAR from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842972/how-do-i-run-a-class-in-a-war-from-the-command-line)