# How to run java class from a war file deployed in tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have web application inside it I have a timer in a main method I wont to lunch the timer from a command line when I did this command : 
**java -classpath mywar.war my.packege.myclass**
I got main class not found

Comment: Below question is an exact match of your's, you can check the answers suggested there:    
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842972/how-do-i-run-a-class-in-a-war-from-the-command-line    
I'm not sure of your exact requirement but you can also expose your timer code via a Rest call and use curl, browser or any other rest client to run it.

Answer (score -1):

That won't work. The class files are in a different place in a WAR file compared to a JAR file. You can't use the two interchangeably. You'll need to repackage your code as a JAR file.

Better still, package your code as a JAR in a separate 'project' and then place the JAR in WEB-INF/lib in the WAR file. i.e. treat the JAR file as a dependency.