# Java 8 and spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a java 8 webservice app with spark and using maven. What im trying to achieve is to start the app locally through the command line and haven't found how to do it. How could I do it?

Comment: It's all packaged in a jar, right?  What's wrong with `java -jar`?  If that doesn't work, we're going to need more details to be of any help.

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie it's packaged as a war

Comment: war file can be started the same way - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842972/how-do-i-run-a-class-in-a-war-from-the-command-line) and don't forget to set master in spark to `local[n]` as [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties)